# What do I have to do/set to keep browser's session for a long time among many IPs?

Tags: php, apache, session

Imagine the following scenario:

1) User comes to a site
2) User adds 5 products to their cart on the site:

`session_start();`
`$_SESSION['cart'] = array(1,4,7,12,20);`

3) User closes the lid of their laptop and puts the PC to sleep
4) 8 hours pass
5) User moves to another location, another internet connection, another IP
6) User opens the lid of their laptop, resuming the browser
**7) The products are still in the cart**

How do we achieve that the step 7 can/will happen?

Comment: (1) if you run `suhosin`, disable the ip check (it's not present in vanilla PHP) (2) set the garbage collector for sessions to as long as you like (3) be aware that on a _shared_ server other garbage collectors might interfere, in which case you alter the configuration to store your sessions in a dedicated / different location.

Comment: Did you consider to implement your own session mechanism and store session variables into a database?

Comment: A session isn't the way to go in this scenario. You should only store a small amount of data inside it, like `user_id`, and `password_hash`. The session internally uses serialization that increases amount of the data to be stored. If you store a large amount of the data, it will slow down an access. Also, sessions are meant to be used for singular use since the beginning (A user should  be able to access the stuff from One IP)

Comment: If you're going to store such kind of data, you end up violating the `SRP` and the `POLS`

Answer (score 0):

1. session_cart_id(rand) set cookie with session_cart_id independent from session, long living, persistent etc. (like rememberme cookie for login)
2. store somewhere session_cart_id -> cart content
3. on session start, load items from store, if session_cart_id isset